# How to get thread state using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I'm in the process of modifying some legacy code to use Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. This application has a parent broker process that fires off threads asynchronously and then monitors their state using getState() calls. Now that the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`'s `execute()` method is being used to fire off the child threads, `getState()` always returns "NEW", even after the run() method of the child thread has completed.

One alternative would be to manually maintain a property within the child thread object that provides state information but I was wondering if there was a known method for obtaining thread state when using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Comment: The primary reason is for external monitoring purposes. We have a web page that displays the number of threads and their state.

Comment: awesome question. I also need this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be passing a class that extends `Thread` to `execute()` when you should be passing a class that implements `Runnable`.  If that is the case then your `Thread` class will *never* be started and will always show up as the state `NEW` which makes sense.

The [`execute()` method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29) takes a `Runnable` class. The only reason why your code is working is that `Thread` also implements runnable.  The `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` class manages its own threads internally.  Your `Thread` class is then never started as a thread and only its `run()` method will ever be called.

Answer (score 2):

Instead using Runnable use Callable and instead using execute use submit.

```
Sample usage for Callable

    private class TaskCallable implements Callable<SomeResponse> {
        private final SomeRequest request;

        public TaskCallable (final SomeRequest request) {
            this.request = request;
        }

        public SomeResponse call() throws Exception {
            SomeResponse response = someService.getData(request);
            return response;
        }
    }

    TaskCallable callable = new TaskCallable(request);
    Future<SomeResponse> future = pooledExecutor.submit(callable);
```

you can check future.isDone()